# How many connections does Object Explorer use in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, dac

I recently enabled DAC and noticed this error when first trying to connect with object explorer in SSMS:

> Cannot connect to admin:servername
>
> Dedicated administrator connections are not supported via SSMS as it
>   establishes multiple connections by design.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer)

It works fine via sqlcmd or just doing File>New>Database Engine Query.

My question is, how many default connections are made when you connect to a server in Object Explorer? I would guess if you have it configured to spawn a new query window that would be another connection? The SQL Server Agent?

I understand this answer: [Is it possible to estabilish Dedicated Administrator Connection (DAC) using SSMS?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17976/is-it-possible-to-estabilish-dedicated-administrator-connection-dac-using-ssms) but I was just curious what connections are made by default.

Thanks!

Comment: There is also a background connection for Intellisense queries.

Comment: I suspect this might vary based on which version of SSMS you're using as well. The last few versions (17, 18) have optimized the SMO usage quite a bit, for example. But it's definitely > 1

Comment: FWIW, the drop-down for databases in a query windows doesn't work either when in single user or DAC. Not sure if it uses intellisense to its own connection. A trace can of course find out, but I can imagine what different actions can spawn their own sessions, hence the answer to the question would be "it depends on what you do in OE".